# Load a saved Doc2Vec model in Colab

Tags: python, gensim, google-colaboratory, doc2vec

I have trained and saved a model with doc2vec in colab as

```
model = gensim.models.Doc2Vec(vector_size=size_of_vector, window=10, min_count=5, workers=16,alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.025, epochs=40)
model.build_vocab(allXs)
model.train(allXs, epochs=model.epochs, total_examples=model.corpus_count)
```

The model is saved in a folder not accessible from my drive but which I can see as:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, getsize
from operator import itemgetter

files = [(f, getsize(f)) for f in listdir('.') if isfile(f)]
files.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

for f, size in files:
    print ('{} {}'.format(size, f))
print ('({} files {} total size)'.format(len(files), sum(f[1] for f in files)))
```

The output is:

```
79434928 Model_after_train.docvecs.vectors_docs.npy
9155086 Model_after_train
1024 .rnd
(3 files 88591038 total size)
```

To move the two files in the same shared directory as the notebook

```
folder_id = FolderID

for f, size in files:
  if 'our_first_lda' in f:  
    file = drive.CreateFile({'parents':[{u'id': folder_id}]})
    file.SetContentFile(f)
    file.Upload()
```

The problem that I am facing now are two:
1) gensim creates two files when saving the model. Which one should I load?

2) when I try to load a file or the other with:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
# 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3')

file_id = FileID


import io
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
downloaded = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(downloaded, request)
done = False
while done is False:
  _, done = downloader.next_chunk()
model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec.load(downloaded.read())
```

I am not able to load the model getting the error:

```
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `gensim`, but from a look at the docs, here's what I think is going on:

1. You're getting two files because you passed [`separately=True` to save](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec.save), which is saving large numpy arrays in the output as separate files. You'll want to copy *both* files around.
2. Based on the [load docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec.load), you want to pass a filename, *not* the contents of the file. So when fetching the file from Drive, save to a file, and pass `mmap='r'` to `load`.

If that doesn't get you up and running, it'd be helpful to see a complete example (eg with fake data).

Comment: The default value for `separately` is `None`. However, from documentation it seems that "if None - automatically detect large numpy/scipy.sparse arrays in the object being stored, and store them into separate files", which is a quite counterintuitive. The other possibility is to use `list of str` which seems to create again two separated files: "if list of str - this attributes will be stored in separate files, the automatic check is not performed in this case".  However, trying `separately='list of str'` I get `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`